# Find the probability that more than twelve of the selected children have exactly two siblings.

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

It is known that $30$% of the $10$-year old children in a city have exactly two siblings. Twenty $10$-year olds are selected at random. Find the probability that more than $12$ of the selected children have exactly two siblings.

Work: $30$% of $20$ is $6$. But I'm not sure how to find the probability that more than $12$ have two siblings.

Comment: ... Assuming no twins, really close pregnancies, or adoptions?  The keyword(s) is "**binomial distribution**".

Comment: Do you know the binomial distribution?

Comment: Would it be: n=20 p=0.3 X=12 ?

Comment: @Lisa . Those are the parameters for exactly 12, so you are going to have to sum from 13 to 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sequence of $20$ Bernoulli trials with success rate $0.30$ (success meaning "has the required number of siblings").   The count of such successes in the sequence has a **Binomial Distribution.**

Do you know what that means?

> $$~N\sim \mathcal{Bin}(20, 0.30) \iff \Pr(N{=}k)~=~\dbinom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \quad \Big[k\in\{0,.., n\}\Big]$$

---

> $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X > 12) ~= & ~\sum\limits_{k=13}^{20}\dbinom{20}{k}(0.30)^k(0.70)^{20-k} \\ = & ~ 0.00127887960422022012\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes. I have the formula f(x) = P(X = x) = (nCx)(p^x)(1-p)^(n-x)
20C12 * (0.3^12) * (1-0.3)^(20-12)?

Comment: @Lisa  Right! Then $P(X>12) = P(X=13)+P(X=14)+\ldots+P(X=20)$

Comment: The answer I get is 0.00127888. I used R programming and entered the data so I didn't have to do it all by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It is interesting to note that if the population is 30% and you are testing a sample and questioning the probability of getting 60% then the size of the sample matters a lot. If you sampled only 10 children instead of 20 your chance of getting 60% with two siblings would be over 8 times greater!